# Are there any two-variable functions that can be decomposed as both the sum and product of single-variable functions?

Tags: functions

Are there functions  $f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that there exist  $g,h,w,z$ each $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that both
$$f(x,y)=g(x)h(y) $$
and $$f(x,y)=w(x)+z(y)$$
hold for all $x,y$?

Comment: Only option is either $g(x)$ or $h(y)$ is a constant, and the corresponding $w$ or $z$ is a constant as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $h$ is not constant then $\exists a, b \in \mathbb{R}, h(a) \neq h(b)$ so :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lclcl} f(x, a) & = & g(x) h(a) & = & w(x) + z(a) \\ f(x, b) & = & g(x) h(b) & = & w(x) + z(b) \end{array}\right.$$
Subtracting:
$$g(x) (h(a) - h(b)) = z(a) - z(b)$$
and finally :
$$g(x) = \dfrac{z(a) - z(b)}{h(a) - h(b)}$$
$g$ is then constant.
We deduce that $h$ or $g$ is a constant which means $f$ is a function of $x$ only or $y$ only :
$$\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}, f(x, y) = \lambda g(x) \text{ or } \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}, f(x, y) = \lambda h(y)$$